# regex in java; replace character with other character

Tags: java, regex

I have a String as below:

```
String toModify= 
    "T600XX MAG4292505 0120153P+000000335.20GBP+000000001.0000+0000335.2001+00000 +000001";
```

I have to replace `01` written before 2nd dot with `95`.

Expected result of the modified String should be:

```
String modified= 
    "T600XX MAG4292505 0120153P+000000335.20GBP+000000095.0000+0000335.2001+00000 +000001";
```

Please note:

1. Position of `01` is not fixed from starting position
2. It is fixed that `01` will come just before 2nd `.`
3. It is fixed that `01` will come after 2nd `+`
4. It is fixed that `01` will come after `GBP` and `GBP` will come
   only one time in the String

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Maybe something like this: _https://regex101.com/r/sJ8eY2/1_

Answer (score 0):

I used below code and it is working fine

```
int indexOf2ndDot=toModify.indexOf(".",toModify.indexOf("GBP"));   
toModify =toModify.substring(0,indexOf2ndDot-2)+"95"+toModify.substring(indexOf2ndDot);
```

If is there any better solution using regex, please suggest.